# Is this function bounded and what about uniform continuity?

Tags: uniform-continuity

There is a function $ \phi  (x): \mathbb{R}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies conditions (1) and (2).

(1): $\langle\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2),x_1-x_2\rangle \leq \gamma_1 \| x_1-x_2 \|^2$

(2): $ (\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2))^T (\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2))   \leq \beta \,\|x_1-x_2\|^2+\rho \langle\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2),x_1-x_2\rangle$, where  $\beta$ and $\rho$  are any real numbers.

$x_1$,  and   $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and are $\in L\infty$.

$\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is inner product, and $\| \cdot \|$  is the  2-norm. $T$= transpose

What can we say about boundedness($\in L\infty$) and uniformly continuity of $\phi$ ?

What if $\phi:\mathbb{R} \longmapsto  \mathbb{R}$ and  $x_1, x_2 \in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Here is my solution= I know that since in the worst case, the right-hand side of (2) can be $\infty$, by letting $\phi $=$\infty$ in (2) we have $\infty\le\infty$ which is a mathematical contradiction. Hence $\phi $ should be bounded.is it correct?

about uniform continuity: if $\phi:\mathbb{R} \longmapsto  \mathbb{R}$ and  $x_1, x_2 \in\mathbb{R}$ from (1) we can write (3)=$(\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2))\over (x_1-x_2)$$\le \gamma_1$, then since $\phi$ proved to be bounded (in previous part) and **$x_1$,   $x_2$ are bounded**, Hence (3) is bounded. in fact we proved that derivative of $\phi$ is bounded, which is a sufficient for uniform continuity. is it correct?what if $\phi$ and $x_1-x_2$ were vectors?

Comment: Please have a look on this page , to have an ida about  writing questions, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference.  ALso, I would like to say welcome for you on this site as you are new, and at the same time, be aware that during asking a question it is favorable to state your point of view, and what did you try solving it .

Comment: Dear friend thanks for your advice.